# Iframe doesn't scroll on mobile phone correctly

Tags: javascript, html, css, iframe

I have a web site http://potcoava.cu.cc/ just making for fun and I just can't figure out how to make the iframe scroll on mobile devices.If I just put an value to iframe height will work but I want the height to be 100% to be responsive :

**The css:**

```
.iframeHolder{  
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    position:fixed;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch !important;
    overflow:auto !important;}

iframe{
    width:100%;
    height:100%;}
```

**HTML:**

```
<div class="iframeHolder"> 
 <iframe src="acasa.html" frameborder="0" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0" scrolling="yes" name="frame"></iframe>
</div>
```

What can I do ? It is something wrong or should I make something in js?

Comment: Whats the iframes code?

Comment: like the website of iframe or what? all the iframe code is up there

Comment: Nope. Wheres acasa.html?

Comment: And what exactly doesnt work??

Comment: it scroll half of the iframe .. but when i put  height :1000px the iframe gonna scroll al to 1000px and height 100% don;t work

Comment: acasa.html just have a div in  middle with :
 position:absolute;
 width:90%;
 left:5%;
 top:10%;
 min-height:500;
 height:auto;
 background:rgba(1,1,1,0.7);
 color:white;
 font-size:3.5em;
 text-align:center;
 font-family:cadrane;
 overflow:hidden;   BUT i don't think that is the problem because i target other page with different content and all are the same dont;t scroll enough

Comment: doesn't work height:auto it just scroll the same amount of the iframe but the iframe is like 300px

Comment: i've found the problem ,i haved this @media screen and (max-height:480px) and it was change the height of the div in pages where i targe the iframe ..